# SQL max and min dates with filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

The following account closed on 1/19/2018, then reopened on 2/27/2018, then closed again on 3/26/2018.  How do I write the sql to capture when this account was opened and closed.  The closerestrictind = 'C' is when the account was closed.

We are working in a data warehouse where the data is loaded everyday to capture all the history.

It should look like this for acct 1234:

```
closed on 1/19/2018
re-opened on 2/27/2018
closed on 3/26/2018
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the version of SQL Server you are using. And also the expected results.

Comment: If the rows with 'C' means it was closed, How come the account was opened more than one time ?

Comment: SQL 2014 - same client, so we reused the same account number if client decides to come back.

Comment: Google "Gaps and Islands problem" and you will find many examples of solutions to this common question.

Comment: Is there some hidden meaning to the open date and expiration date columns? For example, an open request occurs before the expiration date for a closure ends?

Comment: The open date is the original date the account was opened.  It never changes no matter if they opened the acct 10 yrs ago.  You can disregard this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select acctnbr, effectivedate,
       (case when closerestrictedind = 'C' then 'closed' else 'opened' end) as action
from (select t.*, lag(closerestrictedind) over (partition by acctnbr order by effectivedate) as prev_cr
      from t
     ) t
where prev_cr <> closerestrictedind;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works great!  I have to start using this LAG function more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two select statements, the first one with row_number() partition by acctnbr, order by date... save it in tmp table

The second select, inner join this table with itself, t1 and t2.

Where t1.closerestrictedind = 'C'

And the join where t1.rownum > t2.rownum +1